# Overflow auto and position absolute issue

Tags: css

I have "container" with overflow: auto. Inside this die i have "child" div with position: relative. Inside a child div I have a "banner" div with position: absolute. I want to show the banner at top right corner of child.But i m unable to see the banner.

If I comment the overflow:auto statement of the  "container" div , then I am able to see.
But I the container div to have overflow to get a scroll if content increases. Please see the following code.

Html

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="child">
        <div class="banner">
            Banner
        </div>        
    </div>
</div>
```

Css

```
.container{
    max-height: 200px;
    overflow: auto;
    border: 2px solid blue;
    margin-top: 50px;
}
.child{
    position: relative;
    width: 200px;
    height: 50px;
    border: #000;
    background-color: green;
}
.banner{
    position: absolute;
    top: -20px;
    left:10px;
    height: 20px;
    width: 150px;
    border: 1px solid red;
    background-color: #ccc;
    color: #000;
    z-index: 400;
}
```

Please refer the jsfiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/anu1718/XDLm5/

Comment: Due to absolute positioning in a relative parent the upper-most point for the banner would be 0px. It's height is 20px and it's top position is -20px which means it is placed beyond the parents display parameters. Set it's top to 0px and it should display.

Comment: in `.banner` top is set negative, so it will go up, making it not visible. Put top 0 or positive if you want it to go down.

Comment: But I need it at top right , like tooltip.

Answer (score 1):

on the banner css instead of left use `right:0px` also use `top:0px;`
you can refer to this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/XDLm5/1/

Comment: `I want to show the banner at top right corner of child.But i m unable to see the banner`. This is what you have written in your question. **You want to be adjacent to the child?**

Comment: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XDLm5/2/) you can refer this. If this helped please mark the answer as correct answer, so the question is closed

Comment: So, this is what you wanted to achieve?

Comment: yes, But now the problem is I m getting scrollbar. why cant it just on the top of the parent element as i gave zindex. Why it is taking space of the parent

Comment: it is taking parents space because it is inside parent. If you want it as tool-tip you can place it outside the container and then can position it according to your need.